# How do PR checkers work?

Tags: pagerank, tools

**How do the millions of online 'pagerank checker' tools work?**

Don't get me wrong, pagerank means very little to me, I just wondered how they give you a pagerank number, given that many of them give you a different score to other tools...

Comment: This belongs on SO. Since they obviously answered it previously I'll just close it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344917/getting-google-pagerank-via-an-api-php